# IDA memory mirroring

Tags: ida, memory

I am trying to reverse engineer an embedded firmware in IDA. It mirrors memory address 0x80000000-0x81FFFFF to 0xA0000000-0xA1FFFFFF.
How do I setup IDA to recognise memory mirroring.

Comment: What CPU is this?